# Bundled Products Showing as "In Stock" but "Only 0 Left"

Tags: configuration, magento-1.9, bundled-product

I was wondering if someone could help with this issue? I have 3 sites all running Magento C.E. 1.9.0 and the issue appears on all.

For my **Bundled Products** the Availability shows as "In Stock", however, it says "Only 0 left"

Here is a link to a product with the issue:  http://airwavewirelessnetworks.com/access-points/ap110.html

I appreciate any insight on how to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the code that prints `Only 0 left`?

Comment: That likely comes from `cataloginventory/stockqty/default.phtml` or `cataloginventory/stockqty/composite.phtml`.

Answer (score 1):

So this message should only be shown when the function `Mage_CatalogInventory_Block_Stockqty_Abstract::isMsgVisible` returns true.

The default function checks the following

1. That the stock quantity is greater than 0
2. That the stock quantity is less than or equal to the threshold quantity for displaying the message.

The function looks as follows.

```
public function isMsgVisible()
{
    return ($this->getStockQty() > 0 && $this->getStockQty() <= $this->getThresholdQty());
}
```

I would suggest that you can look into this function and see what is happening with your product. My thinking is either this function is rewritten for bundle products or the threshold quantity is set wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the code in the bundle/avaliablity.phtml file or simply hide the content by using the following css

**css**

.availability-only {
    display: none;
}